# Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'currentTitle'

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a newcomer to swift and am working on a tic-tac-toe app. I am trying to write the part where you decide the winner. I am telling the computer that if three buttons in a row have the same text of either x and o, display who the winner is on the label named Winner. But I got an error saying: "Value of type '(Any) -> ()' has no member 'currentTitle'."
Here is my code:

```
//Winner X
    if (Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttontm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X")
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttonml1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonml1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonm.currentTitle == "X" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "X"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player X wins!"
    }
// Winner X

// Winner O
    if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttontm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttonml1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonml1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbm1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonmr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontl1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbr1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
    else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O"
    {
        Winner.text = "Player O wins!"
    }
// Winner O
```

Here are the declarations:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Winner: UILabel!

//Buttons
@IBAction func Buttonbr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonbm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonbl(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonbl1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonmr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonmr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttonml(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttonml1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontr(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontr1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontm(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontm1: UIButton!

@IBAction func Buttontl(_ sender: Any) {
}
@IBOutlet weak var Buttontl1: UIButton!
```

Comment: Are the buttons class members? Are they UIButtons?

Comment: Don't you see `@IBAction` at the top of each declaration of `Buttonxxn`?

Comment: [Edit] your question to show the declaration for all of your `ButtonX` properties.

Comment: Please show the definition of `Buttontl1`.

Comment: Dopapp, the buttons I am referring to are UIButtons.

Comment: ok rmaddy, I have uploaded the full code.

Comment: @Will: Which line is the error occurring at?

Comment: FYI - it is standard naming conventions that method and variable names start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase.

Comment: And you can avoid a lot of issues if you choose better names for your buttons versus your button handler methods. The only difference you have between the button property name and the method name is the digit `1`. Try something more like `buttonTopRight` for the button and `handlerButtonTopRight` for the action method name. Or something similar. Make the code easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
else if Buttontr1.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonm.currentTitle == "O" && Buttonbl1.currentTitle == "O"
```

Specifically, here:

```
Buttonm.currentTitle
```

To fix this, replace `Buttonm` with the correct name of the variable you want to reference (`Buttonm1`?).

`Buttonm` is defined as:

```
@IBAction func Buttonm(_ sender: Any) {
```

... hence your error.

Comment: oops! Thank you very much.